# Is it possible to post from my personal Google Photos to a Google+ business account?

Tags: google-plus, google-photos

As a professional photographer trying to build my business and increase my online presence, I created a Google+ business page. However, when I'm taking photographs I have my devices set to upload to my personal Google+ page as I share a lot of photos of family/personal life with my family and not the general public. When I'm uploading from my camera I also just upload to my personal Google Photos account. However, if I go to share an image, the only option it has is to post to my *own* Google+ page:

[image: other options? Just disable stuff]

So my options really seem to just be downloading the image and uploading to the Google+ business page. Or *also* upload images to the photos account for my Google+ business page.

Are these the only options, or is there a way to say, "Yes, Google, I would actually like to post an image from *my Google photos* to *my Google+ business account*"?